# PowerShell set literalpath as parameter path

Tags: windows, powershell

Trying execute that command:
`new-item -Path (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath "C:\Users\hittm\Downloads\openhardwaremonitor-v0.9.6\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitor.exe") -Name "OHW" -ItemType SymbolicLink`

But getting error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rNMb.png)

In Microsoft docs they said that path is already "LiteralPath" but it not work. If i truing execute string in path param all works fine.

UPD:
Problem is in wrong parameter here's correct code:

New-Item -Target 'C:\Users\hittm\Downloads\openhardwaremonitor-v0.9.6\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitor.exe' -Path .\OHW.lnk -ItemType SymbolicLink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in wrong parameter here's correct code:

`New-Item -Target 'C:\Users\hittm\Downloads\openhardwaremonitor-v0.9.6\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitor.exe' -Path .\OHW.lnk -ItemType SymbolicLink`

Parameter '-Path' in 'New-Item' command is parameter for result, for setting parameter to work with i need to use '-Target' instead

Comment: edit your question instead of writing an answer.  Also don't post pictures, have text here

Comment: I write answer cause i solve my problem

Comment: I see then you have to explain exactly where you have made a mistake and accept your own answer.

Comment: i cannot accept my answer until 2 days gone. but i get your point